# My loops are slow. Is that because of if statements?

Tags: performance, julia

I read [this post](http://www.johnmyleswhite.com/notebook/2013/12/22/the-relationship-between-vectorized-and-devectorized-code/) and realized that loops are faster in Julia. Thus, I decided to change my vectorized code into loops. However, I had to use a few if statements in my loop but my loops slowed down after I added more such if statements.

Consider this excerpt, which I directly copied from the post:

```
function devectorized()
    a = [1.0, 1.0]
    b = [2.0, 2.0]
    x = [NaN, NaN]

    for i in 1:1000000
        for index in 1:2
            x[index] = a[index] + b[index]
        end
    end

    return
end

function time(N)
    timings = Array(Float64, N)

    # Force compilation
    devectorized()

    for itr in 1:N
        timings[itr] = @elapsed devectorized()
    end

    return timings
end
```

I then added a few if statements to test the speed:

```
function devectorized2()
    a = [1.0, 1.0]
    b = [2.0, 2.0]
    x = [NaN, NaN]

    for i in 1:1000000
        for index in 1:2

             ####repeat this 6 times
            if index * i < 20
                x[index] = a[index] - b[index]
            else
                x[index] = a[index] + b[index]
            end
             ####

        end
    end

    return
end
```

I repeated this block six times:

```
            if index * i < 20
                x[index] = a[index] - b[index]
            else
                x[index] = a[index] + b[index]
            end
```

For the sake of conciseness, I'm not repeating this block in my sample code. After repeating the if statements 6 times, `devectorized2()` took 3 times as long.

I have two questions:

1. Are there better ways to implement if statements?
2. Why are if statements so slow? I know that Julia is trying to do loops in a way that matches C. Is Julia providing better "translation" between Julia and C and these if statements just made the translation process more difficult?

Comment: You repeated the inner part of the loop 6 times and it only slowed down 3x instead of 6x? That sounds pretty good to me... it should be doing about 6x the amount of work if I read you correctly. It's only <6x probably because of branch prediction.

Comment: What can I do about it?

Comment: If you do 6 times the number of additions, it will be about 6 times slower since it has to do 6 times the number of computations. There's nothing you can do about that. That's just true in any language. Try it in C or Fortran and see.

Comment: One hint: for i>20 you don't need to check if i*index<20 because it is always false... Maybe you have to add your real code to gain more useful answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, I don't think the performance here is very odd, since you're adding a lot of work to your function.

Secondly, you should actually `return x` here, otherwise the compiler might decide that you're not using `x`, and just skip the whole computation, which would thoroughly confuse the timings.

Thirdly, to answer your question 1: You can implement it like this:

```
x[index] = a[index] + ifelse(index * i < 20, -1, 1) * b[index]
```

This can be faster in some cases, but not necessarily in your case, where the branch is very easy to predict. Sometimes you can also get speedups by using `Bool`s, for example like this:

```
x[index] = a[index] + (2*(index * i >= 20)-1) * b[index]
```

Again, in your example this doesn't help much, but there are cases when this approach can give you a decent speedup.

BTW: It isn't necessarily always true that loops are preferable to vectorized code any longer. The post you linked to is quite old. Take a look at [this blog post](https://julialang.org/blog/2017/01/moredots), which shows how vectorized code can achieve similar performance to loopy code. In many cases, though, a loop is the clearest, easiest and fastest way to accomplish your goal.